# Beamsplitter and Dielectric Mirror

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics

Among two optical components. One is a Nd:YAG Laser 50/50 Beamsplitter and the second one is a Dielectric Mirror see pictures. Both of them almost looks like the same. If the specification is not mentioned on them. Is there a way we could differentiate them and know which one is a beam splitter and which one is a mirror ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a Nd:YAG laser? What is the $\lambda_\text{max}$ reflectivity maximum for the dielectric? Is it a 1064 nm laser-line dielectric? If yes to both questions, just window off a portion of the Nd:YAG beam and send it at both of them. The dielectric will reflect 100%, the 50/50 will reflect 50%.